Performance of numba's `typed.List` outside of jitted functions
I'm using numba to speed up a section of Python code in my project. I found that that outside a jitted function, operations on numba.typed.List are very slow compared to the same operation on native Python lists, on my machine the difference is about 20x. In my project I had trouble finding a way to work around the problem, I was wondering if I can get some advice on how to get the best performance.
The situation is that I had one function that accounted for the vast majority of the computational work, which I decided to optimize using numba. However it was a graph algorithm and it required ragged arrays that constantly have new values appended, meaning I cannot simply use numpy arrays, so I refactored my algorithm to use typed.List. This sped up the crucial function very much. However, all the code surrounding it became much slower since they operated on typed.List, becoming the bottleneck in my algorithm, and this surrounding code cannot be jitted because they use other Python objects such as sets.
I've reproduced the dilemma in the snippet of code at the bottom of the post. In essence, the example replicates the overall structure of the actual algorithm in my project:

A large graph (implemented using typed.List) is created, as well as a large set object containing some of the nodes of the graph

In a loop, the graph is expanded with relatively few new nodes / edges, but this expansion operation requires significant computation

Also in that loop, a search operation is performed which ends up testing a relatively small subset of the large graph to see if they exist inside the large set

The changes in step 2 are rolled back at the end of each iteration of the loop


The performance optimization difficulties are also present in this minimal example.
The function update_large_graph performs the vast majority of the computational work. However, search_large_graph becomes slow since lst is a typed.List.
We can simulate the expected optimal performance by changing search_large_graph(lst, reached) to search_large_graph(lst2, reached), which leaves almost all the execution time inside the jitted function update_large_graph, since lst2 is a native Python list.
But that does not perform the same computation unless lst is properly duplicated to lst2. However, the commented code needed to ensure any updates to lst are replicated in lst2 is expensive, even with my attempt to optimize this process through the function nb_list_to_array. I can't seem to find a way to make the algorithm perform close to the expected optimum. Is there a good solution, or is my algorithm unable to be improved unless typed.List becomes more efficient outside of jitted functions?
The replication of the dilemma:
import numpy as np
import numba
import time


def noop_decorator(func):
    return func


jit = numba.njit
NBList = numba.typed.List
# jit = noop_decorator
# NBList = list


@jit
def update_large_graph(lst):
    updates = NBList()
    val = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        for j in range(5):
            val = (val * 295236 + 2976737) % 395687437
        lst.append(val)
        updates.append(val)
    return updates


@jit
def nb_list_to_array(lst):
    arr = np.empty(len(lst), dtype=np.int64)
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        arr[i] = v
    return arr


def update_large_graph_v2(lst, updates):
    updates = nb_list_to_array(updates).tolist()
    for i in range(100000):
        lst.append(updates[i])


@jit
def revert_large_graph(lst):
    del(lst[1000000:])


def revert_large_graph_v2(lst):
    del(lst[1000000:])


# @jit
def search_large_graph(lst, reached):
    for i in range(5000):
        lst[i] in reached


def workflow_iter(lst, lst2, reached):
    updates = update_large_graph(lst)
    # update_large_graph_v2(lst2, updates)
    search_large_graph(lst, reached)
    revert_large_graph(lst)
    # revert_large_graph_v2(lst2)


def workflow():
    lst = NBList(list(range(1000000)))
    lst2 = list(range(1000000))
    reached = set(list(range(0, 1000000, 2)))
    workflow_iter(lst, lst2, reached)
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        workflow_iter(lst, lst2, reached)
    print(time.time() - start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    workflow()


What I attempted:
Not using jit
Making search_large_graph jitted
Duplicating lst with a native Python version lst2
All of these result in performance much worse than the expected optimum.

if the size is known ahead of time then you should be using a numpy array, not a list, also why is numpy tagged in this question ?!

you should post the actual code here if you want people to attempt to optimize it for you, this "minimal example" is doing too much unnecessary work it is hard to see which part needs optimization and which part is there to exaggerate the difference in performance.

The actual code is very large and the main point about performance gets lost in it. I've updated the question to clarify the specific structure of my actual algorithm that the minimal example recreates.

To answer your question, no, there is no way to manipulate typed.List outside of the jitted function as efficiently as Python's list. As the documentation states, typed.List is still an experimental feature, and in fact no performance improvements are guaranteed. IMO, if performance is important to you, you should ditch typed.List and use numpy arrays instead. It may require a lot of changes, but it is definitely the best choice (for performance).

For instance, even if the size is unknown, it is likely faster to convert a list created in the jitted function to a numpy array before returning it.

@ken I've considered this approach, but the main issue is that my algorithm constantly extends and shrinks an existing large graph object. Since Numpy arrays cannot be resized (and I do not have a tight upper bound on the array sizes, only a very loose one), the whole large graph object would have to be copied repeatedly. I think it would be sad if the only way to get good performance is to write a C function and link it, solely because typed.List.getitem is slow outside a jit function.

Dunno how much simplified the code is, but now it seems update_large_graph could be working on numpy arrays completely, Then outside of this function use lst.extend (returned_value.tolist()).  Alternative would be create huge enough arrays and work on them instead of lists as someone mentioned above. You would need to take care of managing such "list-like" arrays, keep their length.
